# Promote the shape of Table

Tags: tables

I have the following table. How can I promote the shape of this table? I can't add any line for saving the space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}[t]{|l|}
        \hline
        $%‎
        \begin{aligned}‎
            \mathrm{N}_{\mathbf{x}_{j_{1}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{2}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{3}},\mathbf{x}%‎
            ‎_{j_{4}}}^{(‎ -‎1,1,1,-1) } & =\mathrm{N}_{\mathbf{x}_{j_{1}},\mathbf{x}%‎
            ‎_{j_{2}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{3}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{4}}}^{( 1,-1,1,-1)‎
            ‎}=\mathrm{N}_{\mathbf{x}_{j_{1}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{2}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{3}},\mathbf{x}%‎
            ‎_{j_{4}}}^{( 1,1,-1,-1) }=\mathrm{N}_{\mathbf{x}_{j_{1}},\mathbf{x}%‎
            ‎_{j_{2}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{3}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{4}}}^{(‎ -‎1,-1,-1,-1)‎ }%
        \end{aligned}%‎
        $ \\
        \hline
        $%‎
        \begin{aligned}‎
            \mathrm{N}_{\mathbf{x}_{j_{1}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{2}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{3}},\mathbf{x}%‎
            ‎_{j_{4}}}^{(‎ -‎1,-1,1,-1) } & =\mathrm{N}_{\mathbf{x}_{j_{1}},\mathbf{x}%‎
            ‎_{j_{2}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{3}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{4}}}^{(‎ -‎1,1,-1,-1)‎
            ‎}=\mathrm{N}_{\mathbf{x}_{j_{1}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{2}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{3}},\mathbf{x}%‎
            ‎_{j_{4}}}^{( 1,-1,-1,-1) }=\mathrm{N}_{\mathbf{x}_{j_{1}},\mathbf{x}%‎
            ‎_{j_{2}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{3}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{4}}}^{( 1,1,1,-1) } \\‎ 
            \phantom{{ }}‎& =\frac{\mathrm{f}+1}{4}-\mathrm{N}_{\mathbf{x}_{j_{1}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{2}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{3}},%‎
            \mathbf{x}_{j_{4}}}^{(‎ -‎1,-1,-1,-1)‎ }%
        \end{aligned}%‎
        $ \\
        \hline
        $‎
        \begin{aligned}‎
            \mathrm{N}_{\mathbf{x}_{j_{1}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{2}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{3}},\mathbf{x}%‎
            ‎_{j_{4}}}^{( 1,1,1,1) } & =\mathrm{N}_{\mathbf{x}_{j_{1}},\mathbf{x}%‎
            ‎_{j_{2}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{3}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{4}}}^{(‎ -‎1,-1,-1,-1)‎
            ‎}-1‎
        \end{aligned}%‎
        $ \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}       ‎
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean with ‘promote the shape’ of a table?

Comment: You had several invisible characters in your code and other strange formatting stuff which was makings it uncompilable. I guess, this was just due to copy paste but please try the code, I have just adapted in your question and see if your problem persists. The question is not clear, though.

Comment: @Bernard increasing the rows high such that the formula and lines be separated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not use *any* horizontal and vertical rules and, instead, simply display the equations using a single `aligned` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\NX{\mathrm{N}_{\mathbf{x}_{j_1},\mathbf{x}_{j_2},\mathbf{x}_{j_3},\mathbf{x}_{j_4}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\caption{Three equations} % choose a suitable caption
\[
\begin{aligned}‎
\NX^{(‎-‎1,1,1,-1)}
  &=\NX^{(1,-1,1,-1)‎‎} = \NX^{(1,1,-1,-1)} = \NX^{(‎-‎1,-1,-1,-1)‎} \\[2ex]
\NX^{(-‎1,-1,1,-1) } 
  &=\NX^{(-‎1,1,-1,-1)‎} = \NX^{(1,-1,-1,-1)} = \NX^{(1,1,1,-1)}  \\[1ex] 
  &=\tfrac{1}{4}(\mathrm{f}+1) - \NX^{(‎-‎1,-1,-1,-1)‎} \\[2ex]
\NX^{(1,1,1,1) } 
  &=\NX^{(‎-‎1,-1,-1,-1)‎‎} -1‎
\end{aligned}
\] ‎
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Less is more. The code of the table would be easier to read by using something like `\newcommand\N{\mathrm{N}_{\mathbf{x}_{j_1},\mathbf{x}_{j_2},\mathbf{x}_{j_3}, \mathbf{x}_{j_4}}}`.

Comment: @gernot -- Great suggestion! I've edited the code accordingly.

Comment: @Mico Defining the `\newcommand` is an very good idea. Thank you.

Comment: @FahimB - You should thank @gernot. :-)  If nothing else, if you ever decide to change the look of the formula embedded in `\NX`, you only need to do so once, rather than in lots of places throughout the document.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look on the `booktabs` package:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{$}r<{$}}
\newcommand*{\one}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
\newcommand*{\two}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{R@{}L}
        \toprule
        \one{N}_{\two{x}_{j_{1}},\two{x}_{j_{2}},\two{x}_{j_{3}},\two{x}_{j_{4}}}^{(‎ -‎1,1,1,-1) } 
        & {}= \one{N}_{\two{x}_{j_{1}},\two{x}_{j_{2}},\two{x}_{j_{3}},\two{x}_{j_{4}}}^{(1,-1,1,-1)‎‎} = \one{N}_{\two{x}_{j_{1}},\two{x}_{j_{2}},\two{x}_{j_{3}},\two{x}_{j_{4}}}^{( 1,1,-1,-1) } = \one{N}_{\two{x}_{j_{1}},\two{x}_{j_{2}},\two{x}_{j_{3}},\two{x}_{j_{4}}}^{(‎ -‎1,-1,-1,-1)}\\
        \midrule
        \one{N}_{\two{x}_{j_{1}},\two{x}_{j_{2}},\two{x}_{j_{3}},\two{x}_{j_{4}}}^{(‎ -‎1,-1,1,-1) } 
        & {}= \one{N}_{\two{x}_{j_{1}},\two{x}_{j_{2}},\two{x}_{j_{3}},\two{x}_{j_{4}}}^{(‎ -‎1,1,-1,-1)‎} = \one{N}_{\two{x}_{j_{1}},\two{x}_{j_{2}},\two{x}_{j_{3}},\two{x}_{j_{4}}}^{( 1,-1,-1,-1) } = \one{N}_{\two{x}_{j_{1}},\two{x}_{j_{2}},\two{x}_{j_{3}},\two{x}_{j_{4}}}^{( 1,1,1,-1) } \\\addlinespace‎ 
        & {}= \frac{\one{f}+1}{4} - \one{N}_{\two{x}_{j_{1}},\two{x}_{j_{2}},\two{x}_{j_{3}}, \two{x}_{j_{4}}}^{(-‎1,-1,-1,-1)}\\
        \midrule
        \one{N}_{\two{x}_{j_{1}},\two{x}_{j_{2}},\two{x}_{j_{3}},\two{x}_{j_{4}}}^{( 1,1,1,1) } 
        & {}= \one{N}_{\two{x}_{j_{1}},\two{x}_{j_{2}},\two{x}_{j_{3}},\two{x}_{j_{4}}}^{(‎ -‎1,-1,-1,-1)‎} -1\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}       ‎
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you just want to increase the height of all rows, please search the multiple posts on this homepage. `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{<someValue>}` will be your friend.

---

I have introduced custom commands for you. Give it better names than `\one` and `\two` and start using those. Just imagine you (or your lector) decides that you should use `\mathit` instead of `\mathbf` the day you present your 100-pages work...

Comment: This method was good, but the horizontal and vertical lines of table will be fade in intersection.

Answer (score 3):

As I  can't see why you need a `tabular`in this context, I propose a solution resting only an `align*`. If you want a box around the equations, you can have it with `empheq`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} %
\usepackage{empheq}
\newcommand*\widefbox[1]{\setlength\fboxrule{0.8pt}\setlength\fboxsep{8pt}\fcolorbox{IndianRed}{white}{\enspace #1\enspace}}

\begin{document}

        \begin{align*}
         \mathrm{N}_{\mathbf{x}_{j_{1}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{2}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{3}},\mathbf{x}%‎
            ‎_{j_{4}}}^{(‎ -‎1,1,1,-1) } & =\mathrm{N}_{\mathbf{x}_{j_{1}},\mathbf{x}%‎
            ‎_{j_{2}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{3}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{4}}}^{( 1,-1,1,-1)‎‎} =\mathrm{N}_{\mathbf{x}_{j_{1}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{2}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{3}},\mathbf{x}%‎
            ‎_{j_{4}}}^{( 1,1,-1,-1) }=\mathrm{N}_{\mathbf{x}_{j_{1}},\mathbf{x}%‎
            ‎_{j_{2}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{3}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{4}}}^{(‎ -‎1,-1,-1,-1)‎ }%
\\[1.5ex]
            \mathrm{N}_{\mathbf{x}_{j_{1}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{2}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{3}},\mathbf{x}%‎
            ‎_{j_{4}}}^{(‎ -‎1,-1,1,-1) } & =\mathrm{N}_{\mathbf{x}_{j_{1}},\mathbf{x}%‎
            ‎_{j_{2}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{3}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{4}}}^{(‎ -‎1,1,-1,-1)‎
            ‎}=\mathrm{N}_{\mathbf{x}_{j_{1}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{2}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{3}},\mathbf{x}%‎
            ‎_{j_{4}}}^{( 1,-1,-1,-1) }=\mathrm{N}_{\mathbf{x}_{j_{1}},\mathbf{x}%‎
            ‎_{j_{2}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{3}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{4}}}^{( 1,1,1,-1) } \\‎
            ‎& =\frac{\mathrm{f}+1}{4}-\mathrm{N}_{\mathbf{x}_{j_{1}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{2}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{3}},%‎
            \mathbf{x}_{j_{4}}}^{(‎ -‎1,-1,-1,-1)‎ }%
 \\[1.5ex]
            \mathrm{N}_{\mathbf{x}_{j_{1}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{2}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{3}},\mathbf{x}%‎
            ‎_{j_{4}}}^{( 1,1,1,1) } & =\mathrm{N}_{\mathbf{x}_{j_{1}},\mathbf{x}%‎
            ‎_{j_{2}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{3}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{4}}}^{(‎ -‎1,-1,-1,-1)‎
            ‎}-1‎
        \end{align*}%‎

        \begin{empheq}[box = \widefbox]{align*}
         \mathrm{N}_{\mathbf{x}_{j_{1}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{2}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{3}},\mathbf{x}%‎
            ‎_{j_{4}}}^{(‎ -‎1,1,1,-1) } & =\mathrm{N}_{\mathbf{x}_{j_{1}},\mathbf{x}%‎
            ‎_{j_{2}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{3}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{4}}}^{( 1,-1,1,-1)‎‎} =\mathrm{N}_{\mathbf{x}_{j_{1}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{2}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{3}},\mathbf{x}%‎
            ‎_{j_{4}}}^{( 1,1,-1,-1) }=\mathrm{N}_{\mathbf{x}_{j_{1}},\mathbf{x}%‎
            ‎_{j_{2}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{3}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{4}}}^{(‎ -‎1,-1,-1,-1)‎ }%
\\[1.5ex]
            \mathrm{N}_{\mathbf{x}_{j_{1}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{2}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{3}},\mathbf{x}%‎
            ‎_{j_{4}}}^{(‎ -‎1,-1,1,-1) } & =\mathrm{N}_{\mathbf{x}_{j_{1}},\mathbf{x}%‎
            ‎_{j_{2}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{3}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{4}}}^{(‎ -‎1,1,-1,-1)‎
            ‎}=\mathrm{N}_{\mathbf{x}_{j_{1}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{2}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{3}},\mathbf{x}%‎
            ‎_{j_{4}}}^{( 1,-1,-1,-1) }=\mathrm{N}_{\mathbf{x}_{j_{1}},\mathbf{x}%‎
            ‎_{j_{2}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{3}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{4}}}^{( 1,1,1,-1) } \\‎
            ‎& =\frac{\mathrm{f}+1}{4}-\mathrm{N}_{\mathbf{x}_{j_{1}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{2}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{3}},%‎
            \mathbf{x}_{j_{4}}}^{(‎ -‎1,-1,-1,-1)‎ }%
 \\[1.5ex]
            \mathrm{N}_{\mathbf{x}_{j_{1}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{2}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{3}},\mathbf{x}%‎
            ‎_{j_{4}}}^{( 1,1,1,1) } & =\mathrm{N}_{\mathbf{x}_{j_{1}},\mathbf{x}%‎
            ‎_{j_{2}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{3}},\mathbf{x}_{j_{4}}}^{(‎ -‎1,-1,-1,-1)‎
            ‎}-1‎
        \end{empheq}%‎

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `\begin{table}[H]`, but just a display.

There are several choices; if you insist on the rules, you're better using `booktabs`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,booktabs,array}

\newcommand{\N}{\mathrm{N}}
\newcommand{\x}{\mathbf{x}}

\begin{document}

\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{r >{{}}l}
\toprule[\lightrulewidth]
\N_{\x_{j_{1}},\x_{j_{2}},\x_{j_{3}},\x_{j_{4}}}^{(-1,1,1,-1)}
  &= \N_{\x_{j_{1}},\x_{j_{2}},\x_{j_{3}},\x_{j_{4}}}^{(1,-1,1,-1)}
   = \N_{\x_{j_{1}},\x_{j_{2}},\x_{j_{3}},\x_{j_{4}}}^{(1,1,-1,-1)}
   = \N_{\x_{j_{1}},\x_{j_{2}},\x_{j_{3}},\x_{j_{4}}}^{(-1,-1,-1,-1)}
\\
\midrule
\N_{\x_{j_{1}},\x_{j_{2}},\x_{j_{3}},\x_{j_{4}}}^{(-1,-1,1,-1)}
  &= \N_{\x_{j_{1}},\x_{j_{2}},\x_{j_{3}},\x_{j_{4}}}^{(-1,1,-1,-1)}
   = \N_{\x_{j_{1}},\x_{j_{2}},\x_{j_{3}},\x_{j_{4}}}^{(1,-1,-1,-1)}
   =\N_{\x_{j_{1}},\x_{j_{2}},\x_{j_{3}},\x_{j_{4}}}^{( 1,1,1,-1) }
\\
  &= \tfrac{f+1}{4}-\N_{\x_{j_{1}},\x_{j_{2}},\x_{j_{3}},\x_{j_{4}}}^{(-1,-1,-1,-1)}
\\
\midrule
\N_{\x_{j_{1}},\x_{j_{2}},\x_{j_{3}},\x_{j_{4}}}^{(1,1,1,1)}
  &= \N_{\x_{j_{1}},\x_{j_{2}},\x_{j_{3}},\x_{j_{4}}}^{(- 1,-1,-1,-1)}-1
\\
\bottomrule[\lightrulewidth]
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: rules]

Here is the same, but without rules; an additional separation is needed between the first and second row and the third and fourth row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,booktabs,array}

\newcommand{\N}{\mathrm{N}}
\newcommand{\x}{\mathbf{x}}

\begin{document}

\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{r >{{}}l}
\N_{\x_{j_{1}},\x_{j_{2}},\x_{j_{3}},\x_{j_{4}}}^{(-1,1,1,-1)}
  &= \N_{\x_{j_{1}},\x_{j_{2}},\x_{j_{3}},\x_{j_{4}}}^{(1,-1,1,-1)}
   = \N_{\x_{j_{1}},\x_{j_{2}},\x_{j_{3}},\x_{j_{4}}}^{(1,1,-1,-1)}
   = \N_{\x_{j_{1}},\x_{j_{2}},\x_{j_{3}},\x_{j_{4}}}^{(-1,-1,-1,-1)}
\\
\addlinespace
\N_{\x_{j_{1}},\x_{j_{2}},\x_{j_{3}},\x_{j_{4}}}^{(-1,-1,1,-1)}
  &= \N_{\x_{j_{1}},\x_{j_{2}},\x_{j_{3}},\x_{j_{4}}}^{(-1,1,-1,-1)}
   = \N_{\x_{j_{1}},\x_{j_{2}},\x_{j_{3}},\x_{j_{4}}}^{(1,-1,-1,-1)}
   =\N_{\x_{j_{1}},\x_{j_{2}},\x_{j_{3}},\x_{j_{4}}}^{( 1,1,1,-1) }
\\
  &= \tfrac{f+1}{4}-\N_{\x_{j_{1}},\x_{j_{2}},\x_{j_{3}},\x_{j_{4}}}^{(-1,-1,-1,-1)}
\\
\addlinespace
\N_{\x_{j_{1}},\x_{j_{2}},\x_{j_{3}},\x_{j_{4}}}^{(1,1,1,1)}
  &= \N_{\x_{j_{1}},\x_{j_{2}},\x_{j_{3}},\x_{j_{4}}}^{(- 1,-1,-1,-1)}-1
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: no rules]

Essentially the same is obtained with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,booktabs,array}

\newcommand{\N}{\mathrm{N}}
\newcommand{\x}{\mathbf{x}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\N_{\x_{j_{1}},\x_{j_{2}},\x_{j_{3}},\x_{j_{4}}}^{(-1,1,1,-1)}
  &= \N_{\x_{j_{1}},\x_{j_{2}},\x_{j_{3}},\x_{j_{4}}}^{(1,-1,1,-1)}
   = \N_{\x_{j_{1}},\x_{j_{2}},\x_{j_{3}},\x_{j_{4}}}^{(1,1,-1,-1)}
   = \N_{\x_{j_{1}},\x_{j_{2}},\x_{j_{3}},\x_{j_{4}}}^{(-1,-1,-1,-1)}
\\[1ex]
\N_{\x_{j_{1}},\x_{j_{2}},\x_{j_{3}},\x_{j_{4}}}^{(-1,-1,1,-1)}
  &= \N_{\x_{j_{1}},\x_{j_{2}},\x_{j_{3}},\x_{j_{4}}}^{(-1,1,-1,-1)}
   = \N_{\x_{j_{1}},\x_{j_{2}},\x_{j_{3}},\x_{j_{4}}}^{(1,-1,-1,-1)}
   =\N_{\x_{j_{1}},\x_{j_{2}},\x_{j_{3}},\x_{j_{4}}}^{( 1,1,1,-1) }
\\
  &= \tfrac{f+1}{4}-\N_{\x_{j_{1}},\x_{j_{2}},\x_{j_{3}},\x_{j_{4}}}^{(-1,-1,-1,-1)}
\\[1ex]
\N_{\x_{j_{1}},\x_{j_{2}},\x_{j_{3}},\x_{j_{4}}}^{(1,1,1,1)}
  &= \N_{\x_{j_{1}},\x_{j_{2}},\x_{j_{3}},\x_{j_{4}}}^{(- 1,-1,-1,-1)}-1
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```